# Non specific order of probabilities in a time step

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm simulating a random collision process. At each time interval I calculate the probability of a collision occurring between each object and all other objects in proximity. Currently if I wish to find the total probability of a specific object being in a collision with any other object it is the sum of all these probabilities. However if I were to theoretically increase the number of objects to orders of magnitude higher then this form of calculation could result in a probability of greater than 1.

The following is my current thinking on this:

I calculate the probability of object A colliding with object B and get a value x1. The probability of object A colliding with object C must be less than 1 since object A could collide with object B, therefore the calculated probability between objects A and C should be multiplied by (1-x1), and this should be my x2 value. Is this a good approach?

If I do apply the above approach does it not more heavily weigh the likelihoods of objects earlier in the list (eg. x1>x2>x3>x4 etc.). Clearly x1 is not necessarily greater and x2, but given identical parameters x1 would be greater. How would I negate this effect since the order shouldn't change the results? Thanks!

Some notes from discussion with [Whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber):

- I calculate the values based on the spatial density of each object, the relative velocities of the objects, the cross sectional area and the volume in which they are within.
- It seemed to me to be logical to assume this since a collision is not one sided (A colliding with B is treated exactly the same as B colliding with A).
- Collision are independent in one step but if A is in a collision with one object it can not be in a second collision.
- Three objects can not collide together.
- Once an object has been in a collision it is removed from the population.
- This is also computed in a finite volume model - eg. each object is within a given volume for a specific step but it may or may not be in the same volume in the following step.
- Probabilities between A and B and A and C are typically within the same order of magnitude.
- The simulation predicts multiple collisions, but since an object is to be removed once a collision occurs this should not be possible.

Comment: Your approach appears to make two important implicit assumptions: (1) collisions are independent of each other and (2) multiple collisions cannot simultaneously happen. What I would like to know is (a) how do you determine the probability values you are using (such as "x1") and (b) how do you ensure that the probability of A colliding with B equals the probability of B colliding with A?

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment. (a) - I calculate the values based on the spatial density of each object, the relative velocities of the objects, the cross sectional area and the volume in which they are within. (b) I may be a bit out of my depth here; it seemed to me to be logical to assume this since a collision is not one sided (A colliding with B is treated exactly the same as B colliding with A). (Also (1) - collision are independent in one step but if A is in a collision with one object it can not be in a second collision. (2) - 3 objects can not collide together)

Comment: Thank you. I suspect that taking a little more technical care in describing what you are doing might help you answer this question. For instance, you seem to be using a kinematic model, which suggests you are computing collision probabilities *within a small but finite amount of time*. That implies that multiple collisions do have some chance of occurring. It also suggests that if the probabilities are indeed correctly computed, then no adjustments would be needed, nor would there be any problem with them turning out to be asymmetric or violating the law of total probability.

Comment: @whuber. There's a second point I neglected to mention in the previous comment. Once an object has been in a collision it is removed from the population. To be frank the time span is finite but I'm actually investigating different values for the time. This is also computed in a finite volume model - eg. each object is within a given volume for a specific step but it may or may not be in the same volume in the following step.

Comment: Okay--but note that a correct calculation of collision probabilities will take into account that removal. Specifically, it will decrease the probability of A colliding with B if any of C, D, ..., Z have a positive chance of colliding with either A or B before A and B collide together. Thus it appears that your calculations may need to compute not only the chance of collision but also the time elapsed before the collision occurs. These difficulties tend to go away when you compute collision probabilities for infinitesimal time steps.

Comment: @whuber it's a great help just to discuss this. Since the volume is relatively large there is typically a more than one object than could collide with object A in any given time step. I calculate all the probabilities before randomly simulating the collisions so if I have x1 through to xn how would I then decrease the value of x1 based on x2 through to xn?

Comment: Have you thought of just taking smaller time steps?  Make them small enough so that the chance of more than one object colliding with any given object is small enough to neglect. (Although this might imply much more calculation is needed, often an efficient approach is to take *variable* time steps, adjusting them to be as large as possible subject to this constraint.)

Comment: @whuber the problem is that the probabilities between A and B and A and C (just an example) are typically within the same order of magnitude. So no matter how much I reduce the time step the values remain comparable.

Comment: If that is true then multiple collisions must typically be likely!

Comment: @whuber The simulation predicts multiple collisions, but since an object is to be removed once a collision occurs this should not be possible. So if A and B have probability x1 and A and C have probability x2 then I test each probability (random number) if A results in being in a collision at any point it is then removed and further collisions aren't calculated for A. I know this is an issue since it decreases the likelihood of collisions with objects further down the list being simulated. I plan on fixing this by making a list of all objects that collide with A and then selecting 1 randomly.

Comment: That algorithm appears to be the key to answering your question.  At this point it would be productive to summarize all the additional information in these comments within an edit to the question so that all readers will understand what you are doing.

Comment: @Whuber I've added the cliff notes of our discussion! Thanks for all your help so far!